# Javascript assign array values to variable sequentially or object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to create variables/object with initial value from array ?

e.g.

```
let myArray = [10,20,30];
const {fisrtValue, secondValue, thirdValue} = myArray;
```

I know we can assign each array value to variable by index.

Comment: Use array destructuring `const [fisrtValue, secondValue, thirdValue] = myArray;`

Comment: Yes. With [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring).

Comment: let myArray = [10,20,30];
let fisrtValue, secondValue, thirdValue;
[fisrtValue, secondValue, thirdValue] = myArray;
console.log(fisrtValue);
console.log(secondValue);
console.log(thirdValue);